# How to get parameter value by name defined at properties file?

Tags: parameters, jasper-reports, properties-file

I'm trying to insert the key value of the parameter dynamically in the jrxml file:

.properties:

> test.1.keyvalue= test
>   test.2.keyvalue= test2

And in the jxml file:

```
$P{str("test.1.keyvalue")}
```

But this doesn't work, I also tried to create a key in `.properties` file:

```
test.3.keyvalue = $P{test3}
```

But calling with the `str("test.3.keyvalue")` converts it to a string.
Is there a way to do anything identical?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use any expression as parameter name. Even this expression couldn't be compiled: ***`$P{"paramName"}`*** - the compiler will throw an exception.

The built-in ***$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}*** parameter can help to solve the task.

### Working example

#### Properties file

This basic properties file will be enough for example:

> text.message = key1

The name of file will be *custom_messages.properties*.

#### Report template

I defined 3 parameters for demonstration how we can get parameter by "dynamic" name.

This basic *jrxml* is using "One Empty Record" datasource at *Jaspersoft Studio (JSS)*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="dynamicParameterName" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" resourceBundle="custom_messages">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="a" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["b"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="b" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["valueForB"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="key1" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["valueForKey1"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="241" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="360" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[$R{text.message}]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="0" width="160" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{text.message}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="360" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[$P{a}]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="30" width="160" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{a}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="60" width="360" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[$P{b}]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="60" width="160" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{b}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="90" width="360" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get($P{a})]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="90" width="160" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get($P{a})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="120" width="360" height="30"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <text><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get($$R{text.message})]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="380" y="120" width="160" height="30"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get($R{text.message})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

The parameter ***a*** is storing the name of parameter we want to show. The expression below is doing all stuff:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get($P{a})]]></textFieldExpression>
```

It is equivalent to this exrpession:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get("b")]]></textFieldExpression>
```

or this:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{b}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

The same trick we can apply in combination with `$R{}` expression:

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP}.get($R{text.message})]]></textFieldExpression>
```

- this expression gives us the value of parameter with name stored with **text.message** key at *custom_messages.properties* file.

#### The output

The generated output at JSS will be:

[image: Output at JSS preview]

---

#### More information

- How to use properties files: [Internationalized Report Templates](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/i18n/index.html#i18n)
- Engine built-in parameters: [Default Parameters](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v60/default-parameters)